# question about homogeneous ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A=k[x_0,...,x_n]$ be a polynomial ring over a field with $n\geq 1$. Let $I$ be a homogeneous ideal and let $f\in A$ be a homogeneous polynomial.  Suppose for each $i=0,...,n$ there exists $g_i\in I$ such that $$f(x_0,...,x_{i-1},1,x_{i+1},...,x_n) =g_i(x_0,...,x_{i-1},1,x_{i+1},...,x_n).$$ I believe we must have that $f\in I$.  Is this so? and how to prove it?

The motivation for this is my trying to prove the bijection between closed subschemes of $P_k^n$ and homogeneous ideals (not containing $(x_0,...,x_n)$).

Edit: I'd just like to note for my future reference that the accepted answer below gives two different homogeneous ideals in, say, $k[x,y]$ which determine the same closed subscheme in $P_k^1$.  Namely $(x,xy)$ and $(x^2,xy).$

Comment: You can write any homogeneous polynomial $f$ as $x_i^{\text{deg}(f)}f(x_0/x_i,\dots,x_n/x_i)$. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe the statement is true. Take for example $f=x_0$ and for $0\leq i\leq n$ let $g_i=x_0x_i$ and define $I=(g_0,\ldots ,g_n)$. Obviously $f\notin I$ since all the generators of $I$ are homogeneous of degree $2$ but
$f$ is homogeneous of degree $1$. On the other hand, $$f(x_0,\ldots,x_{i-1},1,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)=g_i(x_0,\ldots,x_{i-1},1,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n).$$

Answer (score 1):

In case $I$ is a radical ideal which isn't the irrelevant ideal we can prove this as follows:  The condition implies that for each $i$, $$x_i^kf=g_i$$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. If $k\leq 0$ for some $i$ we are done.  If not then for any minimal prime ideal $p$ over $I$, take $i$ s.t. $x_i\notin p$.  Then $x_i^kf=g_i\in p$ implies $f\in p$.  So $f$ is in all minimal primes lying over $I$ and so $f\in I$ since $I$ is radical.